# Unity - how to fast load high resolution image?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to load very high quality images from the server. (4K image 8192 * 8192 ↑)

The problem is that this image is just one of many content. 
I do not want the FPS to be lowered while loading this image. So, I wonder how you can increase the load speed while maintaining high quality.

Of course, I know that lowering the resolution or lowering the quality of the image will improve the loading speed accordingly.
But I would like to maintain very high quality.

If have a good idea or someone who has solved this, please help me.

Unity version - 5.6.0p3, 2017.1.0p1
Target platform - PC, Mac & Linux Standalone
PC - High specification

```
float t = 0;
WWW www = new WWW("http://s1.picswalls.com/thumbs2/2016/06/10/4k-background_065335972_309.jpg");

while (!www.isDone)
{
    t += Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    yield return null;
}
highMat.mainTexture = www.texture;
```

This code takes about 0.4 ~ 1.0 seconds to load a single image.(image - 620 * 327, 230kb)

```
        UnityWebRequest request1 = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("http://s1.picswalls.com/thumbs2/2016/06/10/4k-background_065335972_309.jpg");

        request1.Send();

        while (!request1.isDone)
        {
            t += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            yield return null;
        }

        Debug.Log("request1 : " + t);
        highMat.mainTexture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request1.downloadHandler).texture;
```

This code takes about 0.4 ~ 1.2 seconds to load a single image.(image - 620 * 327, 230kb)

Comment: Is there a special reason why you load the image from the web instead of deploying it with the game? Or why don't you download it once and save it on the disk? That are better options than loading while playing.

Comment: The reason for loading from the server is that the user uploads the image to the server and displays the uploaded image on the screen.
And we will only receive one time on the server.

Comment: Ok so I don't know the concept and idea behind that. It sounds weird without context though. Generally it's traffic and workload you cannot improve a lot. If the user has a bad/slow connection it will take forever no matter what you do. You can compress the image before sending it but that does only so little.

Comment: Add the current "slow" code you are suing to your question.

Comment: I don`t know how to put the code in comments.
Can you show me an example?

Comment: There is an Edit button in your question. Click on [it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45342691/edit) then add **EDIT** and add your code underneath it.

Comment: Thank you. And I added the code.

Comment: Is it the download of the image  or the loading (`highMat.mainTexture`) that is slow? I need to know this before answering. Sorry for the too much questions.

Comment: Fine.
The two codes above are the code to compare against each other.
What I want is a better way than the above.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a know bug that Unity will not be fixing anytime soon. It happens when loading a HQ Image. If the problem is that it blocks the main thread or freezes for that moment then I can provide a solution that can be used to make it load over-time/frame. It doesn't make it faster, it simply removes the freezing stuff.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I'm constantly looking for ways in many ways, but it's not easy.